# How to speed up python starting up and/or reduce file search while loading libraries?

Tags: python, startup

I have a framework composed of different tools written in python in a multi-user environment.

The first time I log to the system and start one command it takes 6 seconds just to show a few line of help. If I immediately issue the same command again it takes 0.1s. After a couple of minutes it gets back to 6s. (proof of short-lived cache)

The system sits on a GPFS so disk throughput should be ok, though access might be low because of the amount of files in the system.

```
strace -e open python tool | wc -l
```

shows 2154 files being accessed when starting the tool.

```
strace -e open python tool | grep ENOENT | wc -l
```

shows 1945 missing files being looked for. (A very bad hit/miss ratio is you ask me :-)

I have a hunch that the excessive time involved in loading the tool is consumed by querying the GPFS about all those files, and these are cached for the next call (at either system or GPFS level), though I don't know how to test/prove it.
I have no root access to the system and I can only write to GPFS and /tmp.

Is it possible to improve this `python quest for missing files`?

Any idea on how to test this in a simple way?
(Reinstalling everything on /tmp is not simple, as there are many packages involved, virtualenv will not help either (I think), since it's just linking the files on the gpfs system).

An option would be of course to have a daemon that forks, but that's far from "simple" and would be a last resort solution.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using imp module? In particular there is a function: 
imp.find_module(module, path) here http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/imp.html

At least this example (see below) reduces the number of open() syscalls vs simple 'import numpy,scipy':  (update: but it doesn't look like it is possible to achieve significant reductions of syscalls this way...)

```
import imp
import sys


def loadm(name, path):
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module(name,[path])
    try:
        _module = imp.load_module(name, fp, pathname, description)
        return _module
    finally:
        # Since we may exit via an exception, close fp explicitly.
        if fp:
            fp.close()


numpy = loadm("numpy", "/home/username/py-virtual27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/")
scipy = loadm("scipy", "/home/username/py-virtual27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/")
```

I guess you also better check that your PYTHONPATH is empty or small, because that can also increase the loading time.

Comment: Indeed I tried this one out and it looked promising, though all default libraries are run at start up time and I can't tell python from which file it should load a module, but let it search for it in a directory, causing 4 open() calls and at least 2 misses. I just wish there would be a way of telling python not to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Python 2 looks for modules as relative to the current package first. If your library code has a lot of imports for a lot of top-level modules those are all looked up as relative first. So, if package `foo.bar` import `os`, then Python *first* looks for `foo/bar/os.py`. This miss is cached by Python itself too.

In Python 3, the default has moved to absolute imports instead; you can switch Python 2.5 and up to use absolute imports *per module* with:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Another source of file lookup misses is loading `.pyc` bytecode cache files; if those are missing for some reason (filesystem not writable for the current Python process) then Python will continue to look for those on every run. You can create these caches with the [`compileall` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/compileall.html):

```
python -m compileall /path/to/directory/with/pythoncode
```

provided you run that with the correct write permissions.

Comment: hmmm... I tried this on the top level call (the script importing the rest), but it just added another 25 files lookups searching for __future__ without any other benefit at all :-/. All .pyc are there, but the order of search is allways: `*.so -> *module.so -> *.py -> *.pyc`, so it makes no difference. By the way it's absolute_import (no s). Thanks anyways!

Comment: Corrected. Yes, I imagine Python has to look up C extensions before Python files, and it'll have to find the `.py` file to test if the `.pyc` file is perhaps stale. I was trying to give you options for lookups that *can* be avoided.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for that! I also tested it with a file that just loads os and turning the `__future__` option before made no difference. I think I can try tuning PYTHONPATH, though I wish there would be a way to cache all those calls from one python call to the other... is it possible to load a module into memory from a given path? Perhaps I could pre-load them...

Comment: @estani: Once an import has succeeded, the imported file is not loaded again. Moving the moment the file is imported into the main script is not going to reduce your startup time though.

Comment: The idea would be to tell python which file I want to load for each module. So I can cache the location of those files using strace and load them afterwards using something like `imp.module_load`. I would be using the knowledge I have about the location of those files to speed things up... but this would not be much, since most modules are already loaded on python start up (like os, sys, etc)...

Comment: I do wonder what percentage of the startup time these filesystem checks make; with cached directory info they should *not* cost much.

Comment: That's a very good point, though python is not caching the directory structure at all, hence all those calls to .so, module.so, .py and .pyc. One call to the parent directory should have been enough. A miss ratio of 90% is quite high... I hoped there would be some means to improve this.

Comment: @estani: Python has *no way* to cache those lookups, that is up to the OS to do that. The next time Python runs it has to make the same lookups, because it cannot know that the modules are still the same.

Comment: Well, Python doesn't do it but there's is certainly a way. Just by getting an os.listdir of the parent directory would be enough and checking the string would probably have a better performance than blindly requesting the os for every single possible file, suffix combination. But the gain will only be noticeable if you have a very large saturated file system and use python as a tool box starting it frequently. Sadly, that's exactly my case...

Comment: @estani: You could try and hack that into the [`import.c` C code implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/import.c). Python 3 has seen a lot of improvements in how imports are handled, you could probably hook into the [new import APIs](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#importlib) in Python 3.3 if you want to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Hacking python is not the simple solution I was after, but thanks for the pointer! If I can't find other solution I might give it a try... though having a daemon would be much faster and require the same amount of effort. In any case, thanks for all the feedback!